# Isolate Scope with $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a custom directive that I am going to put on a page multiple times

```
        <div id="upcomingweekssubnav" style="text-align:center">
            <div style="width:100%">
                <div style="width: 50%; float:left">
                    <h4>Week:</h4>
                    <ul class="weeks">
                        <li ng-model="vm.selectedWeek" ng-repeat="n in vm.range(vm.selectedLeague.StartWeek,vm.selectedLeague.EndWeek)">
                            <span ng:click="vm.setWeeklyLineup(n)">{{n}}</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br /><br />
        <div id="my-team-lineup" ng-show="vm.showMe" style="text-align:center">
            <div id="myteamDiv" style="width:100%; overflow:hidden;">
                <div id="myTeamBeforeDiv" style="width:50%; float: left;">
                    <center>
                        <h4>Before Trade</h4>
                        <div ng-lineup week="vm.selectedWeek" lineup="vm.myBeforeTradeLineup"></div>
                    </center>
                </div>
                <div id="myTeamAfterDiv " style="width:50%; float: right ">
                    <center>
                        <h4>After Trade</h4>
                        <div ng-lineup week="vm.selectedWeek" lineup="vm.myAfterTradeLineup"></div>
                    </center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="thier-team-lineup" ng-show="!vm.showMe" style="text-align:center">
            <div id="thierteamDiv" style="width:100%; overflow:hidden;">
                <div id="thierTeamBeforeDiv" style="width:50%; float: left">
                    <center>
                        <h4>Before Trade</h4>
                        <div ng-lineup week="vm.selectedWeek" lineup="vm.thierBeforeTradeLineup"></div>
                    </center>
                </div>
                <div id="thierTeamAfterDiv " style="width:50%; float: right ">
                    <center>
                        <h4>After Trade</h4>
                        <div ng-lineup week="vm.selectedWeek" lineup="vm.thierAfterTradeLineup"></div>
                    </center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

ng-lineup is the directive name, here is the javascript and template file

```
    app.directive('ngLineup', function () {
    var directive = {
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.week = null;
            scope.$watch(attrs.week, function (data) {
                var myBefore = scope.$eval(attrs.lineup);
                if (myBefore !== undefined) {
                    myBefore.forEach(function (element) {
                        if (element.Week === data) {
                            var roster = element.Roster;
                            element.Roster.forEach(function (player) {
                                if (player.WeeklyMatchups[data] !== undefined) {
                                    player.WeekProjections = player.WeeklyMatchups[data].WeekProjections;
                                    player.Opponent = player.WeeklyMatchups[data].Opponent;
                                }
                            }, this);

                            scope.lineup = roster;
                            scope.pointsTotal = element.ProjectedPoints;
                        }
                    }, this);
                }
            });
        },
        restrict: 'AE',
        priority: 10,
        templateUrl: '/app/templates/lineup.html',
    };
    return directive;
});
```

**Template**

```
<div class="tableRow header blue" id="statTable0">
   <div class="cell">Pos</div>
   <div class="cell">Players</div>
   <div class="cell">Opp</div>
   <div class="cell">Proj Pts</div>
</div>
<div class="tableRow" ng:repeat="e in lineup">
  <div class="cell">
    {{e.Name == "" ? 'No Player Available' : e.Name}}
</div>
<div class="cell">
    {{e.Position.Abbreviation.indexOf("_") > -1 ? "FLEX" : e.Position.Abbreviation }}
</div>
<div class="cell">
    {{e.Opponent}}
</div>
<div class="cell">
    {{vm.selectedWeek == e.ByeWeek[0] ? 'BYE' :  e.WeekProjections}}
</div>
</div>
<br />
<h4>Week {{vm.selectedWeek}} Projected Total (Before Trade):         {{vm.myBeforeWeekProjectedPoints}}</h4>
```

And here is what the directive looks like on the screen

[image]

What I am doing is based on the selected Week, I am showing some data that is based off that scope variable. What is happening is that when the directive watch is triggered, all the directives on the page are being updated, so each one has the same data in it. I started reading on isolated scope, but I am having a hard time being able to wire that up with the watch that I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use scope:true

as

```
 var directive = {
  scope:true;
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
```

it will inherit from parent but won't reflect back any changes made from parent back to directive.

Comment: this did exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that vm.selectedWeek is shared as an `week`. Thus a change triggered in one of the directives would definitely trigger the watch in the other directives. Thus, although you changed the value at one, the change got reflected across. Try to use the bindings property and set it to

```
 var directive = {
...
...
 bindings:{
   week: '<'
...
  }
```

This will ensure only one-way binding

Also, instead of using `attrs.week`, try to use week directly from the controller scope. Mark as answer if this helps.